# Strange EDT violation containing no code of mine

Tags: java, multithreading, codenameone, event-dispatch-thread

There's a stacktrace showing in the simulator which I can reproduce using the following trivial form

```
public class EdtProblemForm extends Form {
    public EdtProblemForm() {
        setLayout(new TextModeLayout(2, 1));
        add(firstName);
        add(lastName);
    }

    private final TextComponent firstName = new TextComponent().label("First Name");
    private final TextComponent lastName = new TextComponent().label("Last Name");
}
```

All it takes is clicking in the first field and switching to the next one using the TAB key (clicking lead to no stacktrace).

There's no handler of mine, no thread started or used by me and the stacktrace doesn't mention me either:

```
com.codename1.impl.javase.JavaSEPort$EDTViolation: EDT Violation Stack!
    at com.codename1.impl.javase.JavaSEPort.checkEDT(JavaSEPort.java:772)
    at com.codename1.impl.javase.JavaSEPort.editString(JavaSEPort.java:4412)
    at com.codename1.impl.javase.JavaSEPort$56.run(JavaSEPort.java:4397)
    at com.codename1.impl.javase.JavaSEPort$2Listener.actionPerformed(JavaSEPort.java:4620)
    at com.codename1.impl.javase.JavaSEPort$2Listener.endEditing(JavaSEPort.java:4718)
    at com.codename1.impl.javase.JavaSEPort$2Listener$3.run(JavaSEPort.java:4712)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:74)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:205)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

This happens always and I'm asking if this is something I need to live it or something fixable or avoidable.

Answer (score 0):

This will only happen on the simulator as it's an EDT violation in the `TAB` key handling. We sometimes violate the EDT in relatively safe ways to keep performance in place. Unfortunately this creates an EDT violation log.

We'd rather have a "false positive" such as this but also catch real issues in case you run into them. So if your code isn't involved it's probably not a problem.

Comment: OK, I can surely live with this false positive, but I guess, I should understand it. And I'm lost: How can be it an EDT violation, when everything happens in a single thread (see the stacktrace) and this thread runs the `EventDispatchThread` main loop?